# Wildfly Log Viewer has to show log4j logs

Tags: wildfly, log-viewer

I am using WildFly9.0 and able to see the server.log in web console's Log Viewer page. My application has its own log files in the same folder with different names configured using log4j.

My question is how can i see those files also in web console's Log Viewer? How to configure them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web console uses the `log-file` resource under the logging subsystem. This only allows the files from the following handlers to be listed; [`file-handler`, `periodic-rotating-file-handler`, `periodic-size-rotating-file-handler` and `size-rotating-file-handler`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-ListLogFilesandReadingLogFiles). Also note that if you use one of these handlers the `relative-to` attribute must be set to `jboss.server.log.dir`.

There is no way to register additional files. The main reason for this was to not allow the server to become a raw file server. Plus there are security concerns around just allowing any file on the file system to be read/downloaded.

Comment: Thank you James. I agree with you. I have already written code for downloading log files. Two days back i migrated to WildFly from Jboss 7.1 and was excited by seeing Log Viewer in WildFly's web console. Web Console looks great. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

With **Wildfly 10** it is possible by adding new file-handlers to `standalone.xml` for each log files that wanna be listed in log viewers page.

E.g. I have added `appenders.log` along with `server.log` to the log viewer console by adding APPENDERS handler as shown below. Also not that each handler requires unique name.

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>

<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="APPENDERS" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="appenders.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```